# Java Split function upon function returning value

Tags: java, split

I am making a function call and using split on the return value.

The function call is

```
<c:set var="locale" value="<%= request.getHeader("Accept-Language").split(",")[0] %>"/>
```

request.getHeader returns this

```
en,en-US;q=0.8
```

I want to split it in a way the variable locale has only

```
en-US
```

I tried multiple things but wasnt able figure out. The closest I got was splitting by "0" that gives me "en"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to define more than one character as delimiter:

```
    String test = "en,en-US;q=0.8";
    String[] tokens = test.split("[,;]");
    System.out.println(tokens[1]);
```

prints

> en-US

The brackets can be interpreted as "one of". The string is split by one of the characters `,` or `;`.